# Организовать счетчик просмотра страниц в определенном разделе Challenge в Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Как лучшим образом изменить или дополнить показанный ниже код, чтобы
получить подсчет и оценку количества просмотров Pin в определенном разделе Challenge и
конкретным зарегистрированным текущим пользователем.
Я начинающий и не хотелось бы использовать гемы (Rails 6.0.3).

Есть модели
Pin, Challenge,соединительная таблица Position, User

```
class Pin < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :positions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :challenges, through: :positions
  has_one :counter, dependent: :destroy
end


class Challenge < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :positions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pins, through: :positions
end

class Position < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :challenge
  belongs_to :pin
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pins, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :challenges, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Для подсчёт количества просмотров я добавил модель Counter

```
class Counter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pin  
  def counter_view_get
    self.increment!(:counter_view)
    self.save    
  end
end
```

Содержимое модели Counter

```
    t.integer "counter_view", default: 0, null: false
    t.bigint "pin_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["pin_id"], name: "index_counters_on_pin_id"
```

В контроллер Pins добавил

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @pin.counter&.counter_view_get
  end

  def create
    @pin = Pin.new(pin_params)
    @pin.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save
        @pin.create_counter
…
      end
    end
 
def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :description, :challenge_ids => [], counter_attributes: [:counter_view ])
    end

 end
```

Для просмотра результатов добавил код в app/views/pins/index

```
<% @pins.each do |pin| %>
   <%= pin.counter&.counter_view %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: А какую информацию вы сейчас храните в модели Counter?

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что посмотреть можно любой pin, а не только свои собственные? Не очень поняла про "в определенном разделе Challenge" - один и тот же пин можно просмотреть в разных местах, по разным урлам?

Comment: В каждый Challenge - все user выставляют свои Pin и просматривают / открывают Pin выставленные другими user .. Таким образом, все Pin могут просматриваться в разных Challenge - отношение многие ко многим через has_many / through

Comment: Этот счетчик показывает количество просмотров вообще по Pin. Мне нужно чтобы он показывал по каждому Challenge.

Comment: Стало понятнее. "все Pin могут просматриваться в разных Challenge" - список пинов отображается в challenges#show или где-то ещё? По предоставленному коду не очень это ясно. Мне кажется, проще всего количество просмотров будет хранить в Position

Comment: Список Pin -ов хранится в отдельной модели и подтягивается в Challenge по  pin_id